# Creation of Min heap from an given array

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, heap, heapsort, min-heap

Trace the creation of the heap indicated from the following lists showing each stage of the process

a. {5, 13, 2, 25, 7, 17, 20, 8, 4} min heap
[image]

I hope I'm doing this right. Before I proceed to next problems I wanted to make sure if this is correct. Any comments or help will be appreciated.

Comment: Looks correct.instead of a picture you could have posted a pseudo code and asked if that was correct.

Comment: Thank you sir. You mean in general or that's what the question asking?

Answer (score 0):

All good.

Verified with [this online visualizers](http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/Heap.html).

Comment: Really helpful site thank you for this. Next I want this heap created to sort in descending order is there anything that verifies that you know of?

Comment: Theoretically you could just insert the negative values into the heap, but it doesn't work with that tool. Instead of `x`, you could use `100-x`, so `5` becomes `100-5=95`. Or you could write your own tool, or download the one from the above site and modify it to work with negatives, or, even better, in descending order - I'm sure either of those will teach you a fair amount.